# How to change db objects thread safely in django?

Tags: django, concurrency, django-database

For example, I have a model:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
   is_free = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   rel_object = models.ForeignKey(Model2, null=True, default=None)
```

There are some objects that are set as "free". I want to get the first one and set it to "not free" thread safe (I need guarantee that other thread can not change this object at the same moment):

```
model1 = Model1.objects.filter(is_free=True).first()
model1.is_free = False
model2.rel_object = model2
model2.save()
```

How to do that?

Comment: are you saying that there multiple instances representing the same row in the database?  Or there are multiple instances one per row and you want to make sure that the first one (what does "the first one" mean?) cannot be changed to "not free"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [`select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update). This enables you to lock the row until the transaction is committed.